# Unable to mock URL class using PowerMockito/Mockito

Tags: junit, mocking, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to use PowerMockito to mock the creation of the java.net.URL class in my code that I'm testing.  Basically, I want to prevent the real HTTP request from occurring and instead 1) check the data when the request is made and 2) supply my own test data back on a mocked response.  This is what I'm trying:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ URL.class, MockedHttpConnection.class })
public class Test {
    URL mockedURL = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
    MockedHttpConnection mockedConnection = PowerMockito.mock(MockedHttpConnection.class);

...
    PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withParameterTypes(String.class).withArguments("MyURLString").thenReturn(mockedURL);
PowerMockito.when(mockedURL.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockedConnection);

...
}
```

The code that I want to test looks like this:

```
URL wlInvokeUrl = new URL(wlInvokeUrlString);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) wlInvokeUrl.openConnection();
```

Earlier in my test scenario I mock the wlInvokeUrlString to match "MyURLString".  I've also tried using various other forms of the whenNew line, trying to inject the mock.  No matter what I try, it never intercepts the constructor.  All I want to do is "catch" the call to openConnection() and have it return my mocked HTTP connection instead of the real one.

I have mocked other classes ahead of this one in the same script and these are working as expected.  Either I need a second pair of eyes (probably true) or there is something unique about the URL class.  I did notice that if I use "whenNew(URL.class).withAnyArguments()" and change the "thenReturn" to "thenAnswer" I could get it to trigger.  Only problem is I never get the URL call for my code.  What I see is an invocation of the 3-argument constructor for URL.class with all nulls for the parameters.  Could it be this class is from the Java runtime and is bootstrapped by the test runner?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you don't need Powermock to test this. Just mock the string url, for exemple to use a file based path ("file://my-test.properties"). this will work, and you can pass the data you need

Comment: @JérémieB Can you elaborate on this a bit more?  This seems like an elegant and simple solution, but the code under test is expecting a HttpURLConnection and I get a ClassCastException if I change the URL string to reference a file (i.e., java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.HttpURLConnection).  Also, how would you verify the input parameters on the request using this approach?

Comment: You shouldn't use directly `HttpURLConnection`, but `URL` and `URLConnection`. There is nothing usefull in `HttpURLConnection`. It's the purpose of a URL to abstract the transport layer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common mistake when use `PowerMockito.whenNew`.

> Note that you must prepare the class creating the new instance of MyClass for test, not the MyClass itself. E.g. if the class doing new MyClass() is called X then you'd have to do @PrepareForTest(X.class) in order for whenNew to work

From [Powermock wiki](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects)

So, you need a bit change your test and add to `@PrepareForTest`a class which create a new instance of `URL`like:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ URL.class, MockedHttpConnection.class , ConnectionUser.class})
public class URLTest {
public class URLTest {

    private ConnectionUser connectionUser;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        connectionUser = new ConnectionUser();
    }

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {

        URL mockedURL = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
        MockedHttpConnection mockedConnection = PowerMockito.mock(MockedHttpConnection.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withParameterTypes(String.class).withArguments("MyURLString").thenReturn(mockedURL);
        PowerMockito.when(mockedURL.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockedConnection);

        connectionUser.open();

        assertEquals(mockedConnection, connectionUser.getConnection());


    }
}
```

where:

```
public class ConnectionUser {

    private String wlInvokeUrlString = "MyURLString";
    private HttpURLConnection connection;

    public void open() throws IOException {
        URL wlInvokeUrl = new URL(wlInvokeUrlString);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) wlInvokeUrl.openConnection();
    }

    public HttpURLConnection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer comes the closest to working.  After making these changes the mock URL constructor is being invoked.  However, it is always returning a null object.  By this, I mean the line `URL wlInvokeUrl = new URL(wlInvokeUrlString);` always assigns wlInvokeUrl to null.  I have worked around the original problem by refactoring my code, but I am still committed to seeing PowerMockito work for this in case you have any other suggestions.

Comment: What versions of PowerMock, Mockito, Java do you use? I tested with latest release and Mockito 1.10.19 and can reproduce your issue only in case I replace `mockedUrl`via `null`. Like this: `PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments("MyURLString").thenReturn(null);` In all other cases my version of test is passed. By the way, I use Java 8 to run test.

Comment: Could you try to run my version in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the difference between `.withParameterTypes(x)` and `.withArguments(x)` but I believe you need to set it up as follows for your code to work. Give it a try and let me know if this doesn't help.

```
PowerMockito.when(mockedURL.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockedConnection);
PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(Mockito.anyString()).thenReturn(mockedURL);
```

Comment: I tried these lines, but I'm seeing the same results.  Instead of using the mocked objects the real URL and HttpURLConnection classes are created and used.  Could the problem be with the fact that the URL class is declared as final?  From what I've read PowerMockito should be able to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the arguments of the real call are not matching with the expected in your mock.

`PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withParameterTypes(String.class).withArguments("MyURLString").thenReturn(mockedURL)` will return `mockedURL` only the call is `new URL("MyURLString")`.

If you change it to:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew( URL.class ).withParameterTypes( String.class )
    .withArguments( org.mockito.Matchers.any( String.class ) ).thenReturn( mockedURL );
```

It will catch *any string* passed to the constructor `URL(String)` (even `null`) and return your mock.

---

When you tried

> "whenNew(URL.class).withAnyArguments()" and change the "thenReturn" to
>   "thenAnswer" I could get it to trigger. Only problem is I never get
>   the URL call for my code. What I see is an invocation of the
>   3-argument constructor for URL.class with all nulls for the
>   parameters.

PowerMock will try to mock *all* constructors (`org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.DelegatingToConstructorsOngoingStubbing.InvokeStubMethod` at line 122) then it calls the first one (with 3 arguments) and mock its answer. But the subsequent calls will return the already mocked one because you told it to mock for *any arguments*. That's why you see just one call with `null, null, null` in your `Answer`.

Comment: I've tried many things in the course of trying to make this work, including a variation on your suggestion.  I retested by changing the whenNew line as you mention, but still get the same results.  Any other thoughts?