# Mock URL for all classes

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have a class `Record` that uses `new URL(Record.SOURCE_URL)`. I have a test base class called `BaseTestController`. Every other test class extends this. I want to mock `new URL` because the `Record.SOURCE_URL` will not be available on local machines.

This is what I have:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Record.class)
public abstract class BaseTestController {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(Record.SOURCE_URL).thenReturn(PowerMockito.mock(URL.class));
    }
}
```

This returns an error:

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: java.net.URLStreamHandler.openConnection(Ljava/net/URL;)Ljava/net/URLConnection;

How do I properly mock my URL class?

Comment: Maybe this post will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512053/unable-to-mock-url-class-using-powermockito-mockito

Comment: @ÉricRoberge, unfortunately it does not.

Comment: You might get more responses if you add tags for whichever mocking libraries you're using.  I'm not familiar enough with Java's mocking ecosystem, but there are pre-existing tags for [mockito], [powermock], [powermockito], and others... most of which I can't tell apart.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the use of *PowerMock* is a surrender to bad design. It usually shows that you failed to follow the *Single Responsibility Pattern* and *Separation of Concerns*. E.g.: if the URL object is all the same for all tests it most likely should be passed in to the  code under test (CUT) as a constructor parameter...

Also *PowerMock* changes the byte code of your(CUT) which results in test coverage tools failing to work.

Also having an inheritance tree for your test classes is a bad idea. This is because UnitTests are *documentation* for the CUT and the code in the test base class hides away some important information about the dependencies of the CUT.

---

So there are some possible solutions.

The easiest one is to introduce a *seam* where you can intercept the creation of the URL. To do so encapsulate the URL instantiation with a *package private* factory method:

TestesClass:

```
   URL createUrlFrom(String urlString){
     URL url = // some code here
     return url;
   }
```

In your test class you can use plain Mockito to create a *spy* of the CUT:

```
 @Spy
 private CUT cut;

@Before
 public static void setup(){
   doReturn(myUrlMock).when(cut).createUrlFrom(anyString());
 }

 @Test
 public static void createSpyAndMoclUrl(){      
   // do call on cut
   verify(cut).createUrlFrom(THE_EXPECTED_URL_STRING);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not easy to format code in comment, so I will post my suggestion here (removed it if not working)

```
  URL urlMock = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class); 
  HttpURLConnection huc = PowerMockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
  PowerMockito.when(urlMock.openConnection()).thenReturn(huc);
  PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(Record.SOURCE_URL).thenReturn(urlMock);
```

Comment: this is not working, it crashes at PowerMockito.when(urlMock.openConnection()).thenReturn(huc);

Comment: This answer is essentially the problem that the user has asked, this piece of code will return a AbratractMethodError, or demonstrate that you did not run into this error.